# iOS: Do I need to release an internal system sound like 1104?

Tags: ios8, automatic-ref-counting, audiotoolbox, dispatch-async, system-sounds

I know we should be disposing of our SystemSoundID's when creating / preloading them, but my question is, if this also is true when we use apple's internal system sounds like 1104:

```
//Play Click Sound
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104);
});
```

Since we never have to actually create / preload them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK No. The system sounds are stored in /System/Library/Audio/UISounds. Unless you load them into memory then you don't release anything.